# BPEL and Java web service

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, glassfish, bpel

I was asked to create, with Netbeans (glassfish), an asynchronous Java Web service that communicates with a external BPEL process.

Is this possible? Can someone help me? or give me some examples?

thanks

sorry for my English, I am Italian.

Comment: Which BPEL container are you using?

Comment: Please provide more information. The BPEL process needs to call your web service asynchronously? Is the BPEL process using correlation identifier? Do you use WS-Addressing? Is the endpoint of the BPEL fixed?

Comment: thanks for the reply, what I need is to create a simple BPEL process and a simple Java web service and ensure that the two communicate so asyncrono. then I reply:
1)Which BPEL container are you using?
Glassfish ESB, java EE
2) The BPEL process needs to call your web service asynchronously? 
yes
3) Is the BPEL process using correlation identifier?
The BPEL process we can create as we want.
4) Do you use WS-Addressing? 
Excuse but I am inexperienced, tell me you as it is worthwhile
5) Is the endpoint of the BPEL fixed? 
excuse but I would not know how to answer you

Comment: I'm beginning now to study BPEL and Java web service, please help me and excuse my mistakes in English since I am Italian.

Answer (score 0):

Invoking a standard BPEL process should be the same as communicating with any other web service.  You can either get the WSDL and generate stubs based on that or you can use the dynamic dispatch API to invoke the service.

Comment: could show me step by step how to do? maybe if you do not mind, could make a practical example of a BPEL process that communicates asynchronously with a Java web service (both created with Netbeans-GlassFish)

thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

A BPEL process itself is a Web Service. So it'll have its WSDL.
Since you are using Async, You'll have to define two partner roles.
You'll also have to implement the callback port for the BPEL Web Service.